# Any hint on how to prove that the two given conditions may not be fulfilled simultaneously?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I have these two conditions for $0<a<2\pi$ and $b>0$ and real.
$$ \sin \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2 (\pi -a)}\right)=\frac{a }{2 \pi -a}\;\sin \left(\frac{\pi  (a-2 \pi )}{2 (a-\pi )}\right)+\frac{4 b }{2 \pi -a}\;\sin \left(\frac{\pi ^2}{2 (\pi -a)}\right)  $$
and
$$ \cos \left(\frac{\pi  a}{2 (\pi -a)}\right)=\frac{a}{2 \pi -a}  \;\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (a-2 \pi )}{2 (a-\pi )}\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad\quad\qquad$$

As I check them numerically, I see that these two conditions may not be fulfilled simultaneously; Are there any hopes to prove this analytically?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{\pi a}{2(\pi - a)} + \frac\pi2 \;=\; \frac{\pi^2}{2(\pi - a)}\;=\;\frac{\pi (a - 2 \pi)}{2(a - \pi)} - \frac\pi2$$

Comment: @Blue Thank you.

Comment: @Blue Thank you again, it worked for this problem, I could prove it using your hint :).

Comment: Congratulations! :)  Now, post your solution as an answer (and accept it), so that we can all up-vote your success. (Plus, doing so will get your question out of the Unanswered queue.)

Comment: @Blue Thank you. I prefer to delete it instead if the regulation allows me.

Comment: (If I *do* say so myself ...) Deleting a question with which you got help is a *little* insulting to the helper. (It's a *lot* insulting if you received an official answer, so keep that in mind for the future.) Contrariwise, posting your own answer demonstrating how the help actually *helped* provides a sense of satisfaction to the helper; that's the entire reason helpers help! (We aren't *paid* to be here, you know. ;) As a practical matter, it lets the asker and helper double-check that everything was understood correctly and/or applied appropriately. ... But, do as you wish. Cheers!

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your comment. Then, I will do it (add my answer) as soon as I find some time.

Comment: @Blue I have added my answer;  is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

By the hint given by @Blue , considering $x:=\frac{\pi ^2}{2 (\pi -a)}$ my equations will be
$$ \sin \left( x-\frac\pi2\right)=\frac{a }{2 \pi -a}\;\sin \left(x+\frac\pi2\right)+\frac{4 b }{2 \pi -a}\;\sin \left(x\right)  $$
$$ \cos \left(x-\frac\pi2\right)=\frac{a}{2 \pi -a}  \;\cos \left(x+\frac\pi2\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad $$

Further, they can be simplified as

$$ -\cos x=\frac{a }{2 \pi -a}\;\cos x+\frac{4 b }{2 \pi -a}\;\sin \left(x\right) \qquad (1) $$
$$ \sin x=\frac{-a}{2 \pi -a}  \;\sin x\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad (2) $$

The equation $(2)$ may be fulfilled either by $\sin x=0$ or $\frac{-a}{2 \pi -a} =1$ where the latter is not valid. Investigating then $(1)$ for  $\sin x=0$ in which  $\cos x=\pm1$, we get
$$ \mp1=\frac{a }{2 \pi -a} ,$$
which never holds which completes the proof.

Comment: +1. Looks good to me! (Thanks for the sense of satisfaction. :) ... Interestingly enough, I initially did the same case analysis as you (*either $\sin x = 0$ or we get something invalid*) and then realized that I could/should have simplified things further. Eg, moving things in equation $(2)$ to one side and clearing fractions gives $2\pi\sin x=0$, so that $\sin x=0$ without having to consider the alternative. Likewise, the first equation reduces to, say, $-2\pi\cos x=4b\sin x$, so that if $\sin x=0$, then $\cos x=0$ as well, giving the contradiction. But no matter; the argument works as-is.